# pandas fillna on specific part of dataframe does not work as intended

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I'm trying to do fill in missing values on a car dataset.

my dataset has the following columns: `name, seats, mileage, price` along with 10 other columns.

For instance, the `seats` column has some missing values, to fill in the `nan` values I plan on looking at the corresponding `name` column first to get the name of the car, find how many seats that car usually has and replace all the `nan` values with it.

Here is my code:

```
seat_cars = df[df['seats'].isnull()]['name'].unique()

for car in seat_cars:
    mode = df.loc[df['name'] == car, 'seats'].mode()          #returns a series
    if mode.empty == False:
        df.loc[df['name'] == car, 'seats'].fillna(mode[0], inplace = True)
```

But this approach doesn't seem to work as the non-null values count did not change when I do `df.info()`. In some columns, this method seems to increase the nan count in a column.

What am i getting wrong over here ? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I changed my code to this-

```
def fillwithmode(s):
    mode = s.mode()
    if mode.empty == False:
        s.fillna(mode[0])
    return s
    
df['seats'] = df.groupby('name')['seats'].apply(lambda x : fillwithmode(x))
```

but that still does not seem to fill in missing values

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to fill the null values per car name with each name's mode value, if that you can use `groupby` and `fillna`:

```
# Initial DF

print(df)
   name  seats  mileage  price
0     a    NaN       72  37095
1     a    3.0       78  20039
2     a    3.0       21  37002
3     a    NaN       79  43251
4     b    3.0       41  31115
5     b    3.0       77  30717
6     b    5.0       73  28443
7     b    NaN       20  40532
8     c    4.0       85  21792
9     c    4.0       51  26383
10    c    4.0       56  29391
11    c    NaN       77  42427
12    d    2.0       53  25393
13    d    NaN       67  22605

# Fill nulls

df.assign(
    seats = df.groupby(
        ['name']
    ).seats.apply(
        lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0])
    )
)

Out[18]: 
   name  seats  mileage  price
0     a    3.0       72  37095
1     a    3.0       78  20039
2     a    3.0       21  37002
3     a    3.0       79  43251
4     b    3.0       41  31115
5     b    3.0       77  30717
6     b    5.0       73  28443
7     b    3.0       20  40532
8     c    4.0       85  21792
9     c    4.0       51  26383
10    c    4.0       56  29391
11    c    4.0       77  42427
12    d    2.0       53  25393
13    d    2.0       67  22605
```

Don't forget to assign back when you use assign as it returns a copy.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion. I updated my code with yours but still that does not bring any result. Can you please check ? Also can you tell me why my approach did not work ?